# VLSM program that ask input of the network address, number of network, and host per network

Tags: python-2.7, networking

it shows this error-- forH = math.log(h,[2])  a float is required
the error said that the variable forH which is assigned for the log function, said that "a float is required"

```
networkAddress = raw_input('Enter network address: ')
networks = input('Enter number of networks: ')
octet = networkAddress.split('.')
host = 0
itHost = 0

for i in range(1,networks):
    h = input('Enter number of hosts: ')
    forH = math.log(h,[2])
    if forH%1 < 0:
        forH = forH + 1
        host = 2**forH
    else:
        host = 2**forH
    if host > 255:
        thirdOctet = host/256
        rem = host%256
        fourthOctet = int(rem*256)
        octet[2] = thirdOctet
        octet[3] = fourthOctet
        if host > 65535:
            secondOctet = host/65536
            rem = host%65536
            thirdOctet = int(rem*256)
            fourthOctet = 0
            octet[1] = secondOctet
            octet[2] = thirdOctet
            octet[3] = fourthOctet
        print 'network', octet
        host +=host
    elif host < 256:
        if itHost > 255:
            thirdOctet = octet[2] + 1
            fourthOctet = 0
        else:
            fourthOctet = itHost
            octet[3] = fourthOctet
        print 'network: ', octet
    elif itHost == 0:
        print 'network: ', networkAddress
    itHost += host
```

Comment: You should show the error and the smallest reproducible test case.

Comment: You aren't called math.log() with the right params. "[2]" is not the argument it wants. Check the API docs, but you are putting in the square braces that are there to tell you it is optional.